# UIEdgeInsetsMake on IOS 7

Tags: ios, ios7

I'm removing top and left margins from UITextView with code

```
textView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(-11,-8,0,0);
```

but IOS 7 and IOS 6 has different results (Both phones are iphone 5). On IOS7 text moves more pixel than IOS 6.

Thanks

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: What is the reason of this situation? Is there any change on method UIEdgeInsetsMake in ios 7?

Answer (score 0):

Check your View Controller property [automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIViewController/automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets), it's `YES` be default and it automatically changes the insets of your scroll views (like `UITextView`), which is probably the change in behavior you are seeing.

Comment: i tried but nothing changed. I determined that there is same problem with my custom navigationBar.topItem, ios6 and ios7 has different behaviours with same insets values